# Is Jabba the Hutt: The Art of the Deal's title a deliberate reference?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, reference, jabba-the-hutt

### Disclaimer: Please keep this as apolitical as possible while still answering the question.

The Dark Horse graphic novel *[Jabba the Hutt: The Art of the Deal](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Jabba_the_Hutt:_The_Art_of_the_Deal)* was released 11 years after the more well known, similarly-titled book.

I find it difficult to believe this wasn't an intentional reference. Is there any evidence that this is or isn't the case?

[image]

Comment: The phrase “the art of the deal” appears to be (weakly) attested before Trump’s book was published in 1987: https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%80%9Cart+of+the+deal%E2%80%9D&biw=2325&bih=1183&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F1985&tbm=bks

Comment: @Adamant Even if it existed before Trump, the public would likely associate any usage of the term with him significantly.

Comment: Definitely. I haven’t found any confirmation or disconfirmation by anyone associated with the comic of it being associated with Trump, but I’ll keep looking.

Comment: Also begs the follow up, if Trump knew about the SW book, did he sue?

Comment: @roguejedi See, I'm not sure I would simply take that as a given, unless you already feel like you have the answer. But, assuming that you are genuinely unsure, I'd say that the underlying question is how strong the association was. If it's significant and likely, then the makers of the graphic novel would have likely known it - or been made aware of it by their editors. Given the question, I think you need to assume that a significant association is not a given.

Comment: You can't copyright a title, that's why movies, songs, and books show up with names that have been used before.  Presumably the content of the two books is completely different.  Even if it were a deliberate reference, it would then be protected as satire.  There would be no basis for suing, and I would think it highly unlikely that he did.

Comment: Complete coincidence, just like the upcoming book _Dreams from My Father: A Story of Clan and 100% Legitimate Businesses_ by [Rotta "Stinky" Desilijic](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rotta).

Answer (score 1):

### The Art of the Deal Title is a deliberate choice, but as to why has not been authoritatively confirmed

[*Jabba the Hutt: The Art of the Deal* collects all four one-shots from the *Jabba the Hutt* series of comics. It was released by Dark Horse Comics on June 3, 1998.](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Jabba_the_Hutt:_The_Art_of_the_Deal)

None of the individual titles are “The Art of the Deal,” and they are each titled:
*Jabba the Hutt: The Gaar Suppoon Hit*
*Jabba the Hutt: The Hunger of Princess Nampi*
*Jabba the Hutt: The Dynasty Trap*
*Jabba the Hutt: Betrayal*

With four completely disparate titles of the collected works, the trade paperback had to be titled something, even if it was just “Jabba the Hutt,” or a variation of one of the included works such as “Jabba the Hutt’s Best Hits, Traps, and Betrayals.”

That it was called something, and something unrelated to the collected works is proof enough that its title is, in fact, a deliberate choice.

However, Dark Horse Comics is not on record as confirming the inspiration for the title.

Relative to Trump’s book, [the ghostwriter claims credit for originating it with respect to the book.](https://thehill.com/homenews/administration/427092-art-of-the-deal-co-author-regrets-using-phrase-to-push-fake-marketing) He does not credit any inspiration.

To date, neither has Dark Horse Comics.

Whether Trump served as inspiration or not, the collected trade paperback is in any case reference to a key theme of the individual one-shots: *deals*, particularly their artfulness in executing them. This reference holds true whether Trump’s title was the basis, or not.

Comment: I'm confused - the mere fact that Jabba the Hutt: Art of the Deal was a deliberate choice of title doesn't indicate that it references anything (*any* title would be a deliberate choice, unless you name your book with a random word generator). This answer explicitly points out a lack of evidence either way, but confidently concludes that the title is indeed a reference.

Comment: No, it answers the question whether the title was deliberate (it had to be), and concludes that whether there was any or any specific inspiration for that deliberation is unconfirmed. Dark Horse Comics had to advise the binder what title to print. This was a decision deliberately made.

Comment: The headline text of this answer states that the title is a "deliberate reference" - it's certainly deliberate, but may or may not be a reference.

Comment: Yes. The headline is a summarized part of the answer, not the entirety of the answer itself, which is then further explained in greater detail.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not seeing it. The question isn't whether they accidentally titled it something (presumably by randomly selecting words?) but **whether they called it the same thing as Trump's book on purpose**.

Comment: No need to apologize. I sought to answer the explicit questions posed in the primary question as complete as possible; concisely reiterated: (1) __Is Jabba the Hutt: The Art of the Deal's title a deliberate reference?__ (2) 
(I find it difficult to believe this wasn't an intentional reference.) __Is there any evidence that this is or isn't the case?__ I try to make sure the title question is answered, as well as any further context raised in the typically more verbose body text.

Comment: I would not be so sure it's *difficult to believe this wasn't an intentional reference*... Quick search on the internet and we can see there are at least four OTHER books with same title, as well as at least one article in a journal and a piece of art (literally sculpture so titled). It is undeniably clever and standing out phrase on it's own, but it's not like it's unique to two publications only...